# How can I seperate parts of a human body to add materials for texturing?

Tags: materials

I have a few human models that I am trying to work with to add textures.
When I select all in Edit mode and ty to separate by loose parts nothing gets separated. I believe it is one solid mesh. There aren't any seams or anything to separate like in the tutorials I have watched.

Does anyone know a way I can take a solid model and separate it so I can add material slots in order to texture them?

Comment: It's possible to combine several materials on the mesh by either creating / using pre-made image masks or by assigning materials for different parts of mesh. For details on second method see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to separate your mesh? You can have multiple materials on a single mesh. In the material window you can add as many as you want. Then just go into edit mode and select the faces you want to give a different material, and then assign the matching material from the material window.

Answer (score 0):

In order to separate loose parts, they have to be loose in the first place:
1- in Edit Mode, select the Edge Loop between the two parts you want to separate.
2- Press <kbd>V</kbd> in order to break the vertices, then RMB to quit translate operation.
3- Repeat step *2* in order to break all parts.
4- You will not notice any difference, but when you select a single vertex and try to move, you'll notice that it's broken, two separate vertices were created by pressing <kbd>V</kbd>
5- Press <kbd>A</kbd> until everything is selected, then press <kbd>P</kbd> > Loose Parts.
6- Now every piece of mesh is a separate object.

This is the answer to the question as is, but you don't have to break the mesh in the first place to assign separate textures to different parts, you can assign a separate UV map to each part and assign a different texture or/and Material.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do this is to select the vertices/edges/faces you want separated and press <kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>P</kbd>.